# How do we know Aragorn's birthday?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium

On the question [How could Aragorn be 88 years old while he looks relatively young?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13467/how-could-aragorn-be-87-years-old-while-he-looks-relatively-young) there is the following comment :

> One tiny bit of trivia: at that point in the books, he's actually 88 years old. His birthday was the day that they met Gandalf the White in Fangorn forest.
>   - Plutor

Then :

> How do you know his birthday?
>   – Earendil 17 mins ago

Is there a quote or a something to support Plutor's affirmation?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

In Appendix B of The Lord Of The Rings, titled "The Tale of Years", within the Third Age:

> 2931 . Aragorn son of Arathorn II born on March 1st.

Later, within March 3019:

> 1 . Frodo begins the passage of the Dead Marshes at dawn. Entmoot continues. 
>   Aragorn meets Gandalf the White. They set out for Edoras. Faramir leaves Minas 
>   Tirith on an errand to Ithilien.

Happy 88th, Aragorn!

Comment: Don't assume, though, that I knew the date off the top of my head, though. I only remembered the connection between those that event and his birthday.

Comment: So, Aragorn's silent wish before blowing out the candles on his birthday cake was to get a new Gandalf? What a well spent wish!

Comment: The weirdest part of Middle Earth is their Roman calendar.

Comment: Actually, those dates are "translated". The actual calendar was a real mess, as you'd probably expect from multiple mostly-isolated species. In Gondor they used a calendar with twelve 30-day months and 5 days that weren't in any month (7 in leap years). The months were called Narvinyë, Nénimë, 
Súlimë, Víressë, Lótessë, Nárië, Cermië, Urimë, Yavannië, Narquelië, Hísimë, 
and Ringarë. See Appendix D for more detail than you can handle.

Comment: @GorchestopherH: did you *really* think Tolkien *didn't* invent several calendars for the sundry cultures?!11oneone

Comment: Haha I figured he did, hearing Roman months among Tolkenish is still pretty funny to me. "Aragorn son of Arathorn II born 2 weeks before St Patrick's day".

Comment: @Plutor -- I would argue that the Shire Calendar was quite sensible, and our calendar is "a real mess".

Comment: He did well to carry 88 candles and a cake all that way without damaging anything.